# Fetching Primary Keys Data From Multiple Tables Using SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to fill comboboxes with data in columns named `ProductID`, `CategoryID`, `VendorID`.

I have tried to fill the comboboxes with three different functions. But I want to know that, is there any other way to fill these combo boxes with only a single query to fetch data.

Basically I need a query to fetch these records from tables `Products`, `Categories`, `Vendors`.

Table contains data

```
VendorID
   1
   2

ProductID
   1
   2

CategoryID
   1
```

I have tried this query but the result is not as required .

```
 String query = "Select C.CategoryID,V.VendorID,P.ProductID From Categories C,Vendors V,Products P";
```

The result of this query is

```
CategoryID   VendorID   ProductID
   1            1           1
   1            1           2
   1            2           1
   1            2           2
```

I Need That the query Result Looks like This

```
  CategoryID   VendorID   ProductID
       1            1           1
                    2           2
```

Comment: sorry, may be you have to learn `joins` first, For a permanent solution, though you might get an answer here for now.

Answer (score 1):

It happens to be a `Cartesian JOIN` for your Query, And it sounds you try to fetch data from 3 different tables, not related to each other. So, lets define what table we query as a string, and `UNION ALL` for all three Queries, so that you can filter it in the Client side, C# or Java!

```
Select 'Categories' as data_type , C.CategoryID From Categories C
UNION ALL
Select 'Vendors' as data_type , V.VendorID  FROM Vendors V
UNION ALL
Select 'Products' as data_type , P.ProductID From Products P
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have 3 unrelated queries that you want to pull with one database call.

There are several ways of doing this, one being multiple record sets (for example a `stored procedure` that has 3 separate `SELECT` statements in it), and another being to use `UNION` and add a column to specify the type of the item, or table name. This additional column is what you'll need in order to put the right type of item into its proper combo box.

I'll focus on the `UNION` approach. The `UNION` statement allows to combine multiple queries into one set of resulting data rows.

For illustration purposes, I'll make the assumption that in addition to the ID's you might also want to pull names.

Your query would look something like this:

```
Select
    ProductID As ID,
    ProductName As ItemName,
    'Products' As ItemType
    From Products

Union All

Select
    VendorID As ID,
    VendorName As ItemName,
    'Vendors' As ItemType
    From Vendors

Union All

Select
    CategoryID As ID,
    CategoryName As ItemName,
    'Categories' As ItemType
    From Categories
```

The result will be something like:

```
ID  |  ItemName  |  ItemType
-----------------------------
1   |  Pencil    |  Products 
1   |  Pens, Inc |  Vendors 
2   |  Acme123   |  Vendors
1   |  Writing   |  Categories 
2   |  Editing   |  Categories
```

Then, you will need to either loop through the result and use a switch statement to decide which combo box to add which item to based on its ItemType, or use LINQ .Where() statement 3 times, one for each combo box, depending on how you're pulling your data. I won't write that all out for you but I think this is enough to get you going.

Note the `UNION` statement requires the same number and types of `SELECT` fields in each separate query in order to execute.